# displaying `shape` values in `ggplot2` plot annotations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display the shape value (`shape` argument for `geom_point` function) in the plot annotation.

Below, for example, I am just writing `'point shape'` where I actually want the shape itself to be displayed. (This is a minimal example of something more complicated I want to do.)

Is there any way to do this?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg , wt)) + geom_point(shape = 7) +
  labs(title = "'point shape' represents data point")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: don't know if i understood you correctly. So something like ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,wt)) + geom_text(aes(label=cyl)) ? where you display the value of cyl ?

Comment: one possibility is to add something like `annotate("point", x, y, shape = 7)` followed by another `annotate("text", x, y, label = "represents...", hjust = 0)` and the `x` and `y` are coordinates where you want text/symbol to appear (which could be outside of plot as well if needed)

Comment: @Ben: could you make this an answer to upvote?

Comment: @ClemSnide Added answer based on the comment. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the title as a custom annotation, which can be done by sticking a point and text together as graphical objects ("grobs"). Here's a little function that will do that, whilst allowing you to set the point shape and colour as well as the title text.

```
library(grid)

make_title <- function(point_type = 7, label = "represents data point", col = "black")
{
  Point <- grid::pointsGrob(x = 0.0 , y = 1.05, pch = point_type, gp = gpar(col = col))
  Text <-  grid::textGrob(x = 0.025, y = 1.055, just = "left", label)
  Title <- grid::grobTree(Point, Text)
}
```

Now you just add this to your plot as a custom annotation. You have to turn clipping off to allow plotting outside of the plot area, and add a blank title with a line break in it to give enough room for your new plot title:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg , wt))     + 
  labs(title = "\n ")             +
  geom_point(shape = 7)           +
  annotation_custom(make_title()) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

or if you need to change it:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg , wt)) + 
  labs(title = "\n ") +
  geom_point(shape = 3, colour = "red")           +
  annotation_custom(make_title(3, "Different plot with red point", "red")) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the best bet would be to use the shape number and link it with it's corresponding 'point shape' using a key-value pair list.

Here's the shape_label_key of all the 25 basic shapes in R which you can view using `ggpubr::show_point_shapes()`

```
shape_label_key <- list(
    key = c(0:24),
    value = c(
        "square", "circle", "triangle point up", "plus", "cross", "diamond", "triangle point down",
        "square cross", "star", "diamond plus", "circle plus", "triangles up and down", "square plus",
        "circle cross", "square and triangle down", "filled square", "filled circle", "filled triangle point-up",
        "filled diamond", "solid circle", "bullet (smaller circle)", "filled circle blue", "filled square blue",
        "filled diamond blue", "filled triangle point-up blue", "filled triangle point down blue"
    )
)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg , wt)) + geom_point(shape = 7) +
  labs(title = paste0("'", shape_label_key$value[shape_label_key$key == 7], "' represents data point"))
```

[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: For simplicity and writing better code you have to pass the shape_value as a variable instead of passing 7 both times!

Comment: Save your plot to a variable `p1` then use this: `p1$layers[[1]]$aes_params$shape` to get the variable so you don't have to type it twice. This assumes `geom_point()` is always the first layer.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments, this is kind of a quick and dirty approach to getting the title with the shape included.

Use `annotate` to show the shape/point, and then a second `annotate` for text following the shape.

The `coord_cartesian` also sets y limits and with the `clip` argument set to "off" allows for text placement outside of the plot area.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg , wt)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 7) +
  labs(title = "") +
  annotate("point", 0, 6.5, shape = 7) +
  annotate("text", .5, 6.5, label = "represents data point", hjust = 0) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 6), clip = "off")
```

**Plot**

[image: plot with shape and text in title]

Comment: I prefer this as it is less "invasive" and still completely customizable

Answer (score 0):

You can add `color` to `aes()`

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color=cyl), show.legend = TRUE) + 
geom_point(shape=7) + 
theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: I am not looking to display the legend. I want to display the point shape *inside* the annotation.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.